# Any way to change new_post_path's default "/new" url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4

**TLDR; I need to have my `new_topic_post_path` link to** `/tennis/publish` **instead of** `/tennis/new`

I have defined a custom route in `routes.rb`:

```
match '/:topic_id/publish', to: 'posts#new', via: [:get, :post]
```

But still `new_topic_post_path(topic)` returns a link:

```
http://localhost:3000/tennis/new
```

However, for cosmetical reasons I need the url to look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/tennis/publish
```

Any ideas? Big appreciations for any answers. Thanks in advance.

(***Also...*** if that is not possible, is there any way to add string in link_to, such as: `link_to post.name, post(/publish)` to achieve similar result? I tried countless variations of that, but couldn't find a way.)

***Edit:** Also, I'm having the links in*

```
 <% all_topics.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }.each do |topic| %>
   <%= link_to topic.name, new_topic_post_path(topic) %>
 <% end %>
```

So straight `link_to "tennis/publish` isn't suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match '/:topic_id/publish', to: 'posts#new', via: [:get, :post], as: publish_topic
```

Then use `publish_topic_path` route helper.

Also you can do:

```
resources :posts, path_names: { new: 'publish' }
```

Comment: `resources :posts, path_names: { new: 'publish' }` worked spot on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`resources :tennis, path_names: { new: 'publish' }`

I'm not sure how to do it for all, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of the `:as` option, which is used to generate routing helpers, in your `routes.rb` file, like so:

```
match '/:topic_id/publish', to: 'posts#new', via: [:get, :post], as: 'new_topic_post'
```

You can read more about options for the `#match` method here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match